# Getting Index of First Non Alpha character in a string C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split out a string (at the index) whenever I find the first non alpha or whitespace.

My Regex is really rusty and trying to find some direction on getting this to work.

Example:  "Payments Received by 08/14/2015 $0.00" is the string. and I'm able to find the first digit

---

```
string alphabet = String.Empty;
string digit = String.Empty;
int digitStartIndex;

Match regexMatch = Regex.Match("Payments Received by 08/14/2015 $0.00", "\\d");

digitStartIndex = regexMatch.Index;
alphabet = line.Substring(0, digitStartIndex);
digit = line.Substring(digitStartIndex);
```

---

The problem lies when a string like "Amount This Period + $57.00" 
I end up with "Amount This Period + $"

How from using Regex in C#, if I want to also include specific non-alphanumeric characters to check for such as `$ + -`?

**Edit:** I'm looking for the output (variables alphabet and digit) in the example above I'm struggling with to be.
"Amount This Period"
"+ $57.00"

Comment: what is the input and what is the desired output

Comment: Your question is phrased very confusingly. What exactly do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split a string the way you mention, use a regular expression to find the initial alpha/space chars and then the rest.

```
var s = "Payments Received by 08/14/2015 $0.00";
var re = new Regex("^([a-z ]+)(.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var m = re.Match(s);
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2]);
}
```

The ^ is important to find characters at the start.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, then you want this I think:

```
void Main()
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"(.*?)([\$\+\-].*)");
    var a = "Payments Received by 08/14/2015 $0.00";
    var b = "Amount This Period + $57.00";

    Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(a).Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(a).Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(b).Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(b).Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Payments Received by 08/14/2015 
$0.00
Amount This Period 
+ $57.00
```